# How to set file encoding in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have some issues in set encoding in node.js.
  I tried to set encoding to utf8 using writeFile function.
  But no results. current file I want to set encoding using node.js was encoded in unicode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> By default, the fs module will write files with an encoding of 'utf8'. UTF-8 is an encoding commonly used in web pages and other documents. File encoding refers to the character set that is used for the contents of the file. Commonly used encodings are 'utf8', 'ascii', 'binary', 'hex', 'base64' and 'utf16le'.

Source from [stackabuse](http://stackabuse.com/writing-to-files-in-node-js/).

To write file with encoding

If **options is a string, then it specifies the encoding**. Example:

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', 'utf8', callback);
```

or  is **options** is an object then,

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', {encoding: 'utf8'}, callback);
```

Check [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) for more information

Comment: I tried to create xls file but is not encoding using the above way